How to drag and drop java application in vs code as same as windowbuilder in Eclipse
I am a newbie to learn java applications. So I don't know too much what things I need to install to use drag and drop in Vs code like Window Builder in Eclipse. Thanks very much!
I tried to install eclipse. But my Eclipse always have error which I don't know how to fix it. Therefore, I decided to use Vs code.
I need some help !!!
